# Database issues when moving a Visual Studio 2015 project to a different computer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC app in VS 2015 Professional on a Windows Server 2008 R2 System and the application connects to a database on it, and now I want to move the project to a different computer that does not have SQL Server (Windows 10 System) . On the destination computer, I am using VS2015 Community Edition, and I was able to load the project into it. However, when running the program, I am getting errors saying the tables don't exist, even though I created the database with the same name as in the original computer, using the Visual Studio localdb. I thought the Entity Framework and Identity Framework (which is what the app's user administration system uses) would generate the tables automatically, and there is a seed method to create an admin user.

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="IdentityDb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=IdentityDb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="IdentityDevelopment.App_Start.IdentityConfig" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**IdentityConfig.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;
using IdentityDevelopment.Infrastructure;

namespace IdentityDevelopment.App_Start
{
    public class IdentityConfig
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(AppIdentityDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppUserManager>(AppUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppRoleManager>(AppRoleManager.Create);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your project have a Web.Config file? Can you post it?

Comment: @EricS Yes it does, just posted it. This is from the SQL Server 2008 computer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Entity Framework Migration tool to migrate database on different system as EF keeps records where database created, On changing the system your System Name changed to so EF thinks it as new database as it didn't know you are migrating to new system.Use **msdn** help to migrate data

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio can generate tables if you are using Entity Framework code first approach (using code first migrations).

By default, in your EF **Configuration** class, **AutomaticMigrationsEnabled** is set to false, which means that this process will not happen automatically, unless you tell it to.

You can open the Package Manager Console inside Visual studio and enter the following command:

```
Update-Database
```

This will automatically apply all your migrations and seed methods if your info for connecting to database is correct. If you have multiple projects, make sure you select the appropriate one in the Package Manager Console. It will usually be the project which has your database context.

Comment: I will try this out this out and post what happens later today. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. If running the mentioned command gives you any error, please post it so we can troubleshoot it.

Comment: I read up on migrations and got it working, culminating with this command.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)